# R apply function pass multiple elements from row as arguments

Tags: r, apply

I finally want to master the `apply` functions in R. Unfortunately it seems I'm too dumb to understand the common examples, which are often not complex enough to represent my use case. This is my example:

I want to replace the car name in mtcars with an attribute, e.g. "speedy car" or "scrap truck", based on a complex function:

```
mtcars$name <- rownames(mtcars)
    
hotornot <- function(horsepower, cylinders, name)
{
  if(horsepower < 200 && cylinders < 5 && name != "Merc 240D")       
        return("scrap truck")
  
  return("speedy car")
}
```

Now how do I manage to pass the corresponding values from mtcars$cyl, mtcars$hp and mtcars$name to my function hotornot() and write the return value in the mtcars$name column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mapply` as follows:

```
transform(mtcars, name = mapply(hotornot, hp, cyl, name))
```

giving:

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb        name
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  speedy car
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  speedy car
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 scrap truck
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  speedy car
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  speedy car
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  speedy car
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4  speedy car
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  speedy car
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 scrap truck
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4  speedy car
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4  speedy car
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3  speedy car
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3  speedy car
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3  speedy car
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4  speedy car
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4  speedy car
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4  speedy car
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 scrap truck
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 scrap truck
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 scrap truck
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 scrap truck
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2  speedy car
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2  speedy car
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4  speedy car
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2  speedy car
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 scrap truck
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2 scrap truck
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2 scrap truck
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4  speedy car
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6  speedy car
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8  speedy car
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 scrap truck
```

### Single Exit

Note that while `hotornot` in the question works having a single exit at the bottom is preferred so you might want to write it like this which returns the value of the `if/else` statement.

```
hotornot1 <- function(horsepower, cylinders, name) {
  if (horsepower < 200 && cylinders < 5 && name != "Merc 240D") {
    "scrap truck"
  } else "speedy car"
}

mtcars$name <- rownames(mtcars)
transform(mtcars, name = mapply(hotornot1, hp, cyl, name))
```

### Vectorized Code

Also it would be possible to write it as a vectorized function eliminating the need for explicitly iterating over the rows.  To do that use & in place of && and `ifelse` in place of `if ... else ...` .  Unlike && the & operator does not short circuit but in this case it does not matter.

```
hotornot_vec <- function(horsepower, cylinders, name) {
  ifelse(horsepower < 200 & cylinders < 5 & name != "Merc 240D",
    "scrap truck", "speedy car")
}

mtcars$name <- rownames(mtcars)
transform(mtcars, name = hotornot_vec(hp, cyl, name))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run via `with` (or `within`) + `Vectorize`

```
within(mtcars, name <- Vectorize(hotornot)(hp, cyl, name))
```

or

```
mtcars$name <- with(mtcars, Vectorize(hotornot)(hp, cyl, name))
```

where

```
> with(mtcars, Vectorize(hotornot)(hp, cyl, name))
 [1] "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "scrap truck" "speedy car"  "speedy car" 
 [6] "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "scrap truck" "speedy car"
[11] "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "speedy car"
[16] "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "scrap truck" "scrap truck" "scrap truck"
[21] "scrap truck" "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "speedy car"  "speedy car"
[26] "scrap truck" "scrap truck" "scrap truck" "speedy car"  "speedy car" 
[31] "speedy car"  "scrap truck"
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't explicit enough: I need the return value written into the column "name" for each row.

Comment: `mtcars$name <- with(mtcars, Vectorize(hotornot)(hp, cyl, name))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also with `dplyr` package `dplyr::mutate(mtcars, name = mapply(hotornot, hp, cyl, name))`if you prefer to work with packages rrom `tidyverse`